# Advice on design: Balancing content and flow on website

Tags: website-design, accessibility, balance

Live site: https://plugmusic.netlify.app/track.html

Don't know if this is the right place to ask, but I am struggling with this music streaming app design. I am trying to make my design as balanced as possible, but I have a lot of awkward objects in weird placings. Main questions are:

1. Should there be anything to the right of the song title?
2. Could the lyrics be in a more accessible spot?

Here is my design:

[image]

Comment: You need to edit your colors to give it more contrast. Those are unusable as is.

Comment: @ZachSaucier thanks for the feedback, edited my post

Comment: I agree with @ZachSaucier The contrast of that dark text on the blue background fails one of the WCAG colour contrast criteria. Go for a slightly lighter/brighter blue background to fix it.  [see the test result here](https://imgur.com/ktRSK5X). This is from the contrast checker website at https://contrastchecker.com/ - other than that, I don't really see anything else that I would say is wrong. The dark text is also a bit small for me, but that's just my personal opinion.

Comment: One tool that I was introduced to is the [WAVE Evaluation extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wave-evaluation-tool/jbbplnpkjmmeebjpijfedlgcdilocofh?hl=en-US) that can help with accessibility.

Comment: When considering how to balance the design, you need to (as early as possible) check the design using mobile view-ports. Most browsers have a development console with an option to alter the view-port to match common mobile sizes. The depicted design fails hard on e.g. 350px wide. Desktop trends toward 16:9-ish, but phones are vertical and the most common view-ports are 350-400(ish)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a few things. The player on the bottom is not needed. You already have the title on top of the page and also you have a play button, so I would suggest just add the timeline next to the top play button and remove that bottom player. The timeline on top would also act as a visual separator between title and lyrics.

Also I would suggest lyrics to be on the left, artist info on the right, because lyrics are in general longer text that would support that left vertical guide you established in the design.

I don't agree with the contrast remarks. I agree there is some weird feeling about it because you use both white and dark text. Maybe increase the contrast of the page ... make the top wavy lines darker, so there would be no questions why the text is white, and leave the bottom half the way it is.

Comment: Moving the timeline to the top would create issues as the user would not be able to quickly access it... they would have to scroll all the way to the top from wherever they are. Or are you suggesting to have a floating element somewhere?